# Cycle to calculate entire week with skipped days

Tags: java, datetime, recursion, jodatime

I retrieve more data from a query, between 2 dates. The dates are the first day of the week of the first week on the month, and the last day of the week of the last week on the month.
Precisly, currently month (for example) have the range dates as is (on Locale, monday is the first day of the week):

```
from 2014-03-31 to 2014-05-04 (35 days)
```

The problem is that the data retrieves are only the working days (for example: 5 days for week) but I must calculate the entire week for 7 days because every 7 days I write data in ArrayList.

I'm building a code to make this but doesn't works because the code calculates only 33 days, instead 35 days and I don't understand why...

This is my code:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date firstdayoftheweek = new Date();
    try
    {
    firstdayoftheweek = formatter.parse("2014-03-31");
    }
    catch(ParseException e){}

    String dateTemp = null;

    for ( String[] result : results) // cicle for every query's row
    {

    count_row++;

    if (count_row == 1)
    {
        Date dtActualDayQuery = new Date();
        try
        {
            dtWd = formatter.parse(result[12]);
        }
        catch(ParseException e){}

        int diffDays = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(firstdayoftheweek), new DateTime(dtActualDayQuery)).getDays();

        if (diffDays > 1)
        {
            count_row = (count_row + diffDays) -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Date dtprevious = new Date();
        Date dtActualDayQuery = new Date();

        try
        {
            dtprevious = formatter.parse(dateTemp);
            dtActualDayQuery = formatter.parse(result[12]);
        }
        catch(ParseException e){}

        int diffDays = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(dtprevious), new DateTime(dtActualDayQuery)).getDays();

        if (diffDays > 1)
        {
            count_row = (count_row + diffDays) -1;
        }
    }

    dateTemp = result[12]; // Save the date for next comparison

    // Do something every day of the week


    if (((count_row) % 7) == 0)
    {
        // Do something every 7 days
    }
}
```

Isn't correct, I know...but I can't think a correct solution...

Thanks!!

EDIT:

I've writed a sample code:

```
package test;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int count = 0;

        String[] month = {"2014-03-31", "2014-04-01", "2014-04-02", "2014-04-03", "2014-04-04",
                "2014-04-07", "2014-04-08", "2014-04-09", "2014-04-10", "2014-04-11",
                "2014-04-14", "2014-04-15", "2014-04-16", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-18",
                "2014-04-21", "2014-04-22", "2014-04-23", "2014-04-24", "2014-04-25",
                "2014-04-28", "2014-04-29", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-01", "2014-05-02"};

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dt_1day_absolute = new Date();

        try 
        {
            dt_1day_absolute = formatter.parse("2014-03-31");
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {}

        String dateTemp = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) 
        {

            count++;

            if (count == 1) 
            {
                Date dtFromVector = new Date();
                try 
                {
                    dtFromVector = formatter.parse(month[i]);
                } catch (ParseException e){}

                int diffDays = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(dt_1day_absolute), new DateTime(dtFromVector)).getDays();

                if (diffDays > 1) 
                {
                    count = (count + diffDays) - 1;
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                Date dtprev = new Date();
                Date dtaft = new Date();

                try 
                {
                    dtprev = formatter.parse(dateTemp);
                    dtaft = formatter.parse(month[i]);
                } 
                catch (ParseException e) {}

                int diffDays = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(dtprev), new DateTime(dtaft)).getDays();

                if (diffDays > 1) 
                {
                    count = (count + diffDays) - 1;
                }
            }

            dateTemp = month[i];

            System.out.println("Num Day: " + String.valueOf(count));
            System.out.println("Date: " + month[i]);

            if (((count) % 7) == 0) 
            {
                System.out.println("---End week---");
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I obtain this result:

```
Num Day:  1
Date:  2014-03-31
Num Day:  2
Date:  2014-04-01
Num Day:  3
Date:  2014-04-02
Num Day:  4
Date:  2014-04-03
Num Day:  5
Date:  2014-04-04
Num Day:  8
Date:  2014-04-07
Num Day:  9
Date:  2014-04-08
Num Day:  10
Date:  2014-04-09
Num Day:  11
Date:  2014-04-10
Num Day:  12
Date:  2014-04-11
Num Day:  15
Date:  2014-04-14
Num Day:  16
Date:  2014-04-15
Num Day:  17
Date:  2014-04-16
Num Day:  18
Date:  2014-04-17
Num Day:  19
Date:  2014-04-18
Num Day:  22
Date:  2014-04-21
Num Day:  23
Date:  2014-04-22
Num Day:  24
Date:  2014-04-23
Num Day:  25
Date:  2014-04-24
Num Day:  26
Date:  2014-04-25
Num Day:  29
Date:  2014-04-28
Num Day:  30
Date:  2014-04-29
Num Day:  31
Date:  2014-04-30
Num Day:  32
Date:  2014-05-01
Num Day:  33
Date:  2014-05-02
```

I expected this result:

```
Num Day:  1
Date:  2014-03-31
Num Day:  2
Date:  2014-04-01
Num Day:  3
Date:  2014-04-02
Num Day:  4
Date:  2014-04-03
Num Day:  5
Date:  2014-04-04
Num Day:  6
not exists
Num Day:  7
not exists
---End week---
Num Day:  8
Date:  2014-04-07
Num Day:  9
Date:  2014-04-08
Num Day:  10
Date:  2014-04-09
Num Day:  11
Date:  2014-04-10
Num Day:  12
Date:  2014-04-11
Num Day:  13
not exists
Num Day:  14
not exists
---End week---
Num Day:  15
Date:  2014-04-14
Num Day:  16
Date:  2014-04-15
Num Day:  17
Date:  2014-04-16
Num Day:  18
Date:  2014-04-17
Num Day:  19
Date:  2014-04-18
Num Day:  20
not exists
Num Day:  21
not exists
---End week---
Num Day:  22
Date:  2014-04-21
Num Day:  23
Date:  2014-04-22
Num Day:  24
Date:  2014-04-23
Num Day:  25
Date:  2014-04-24
Num Day:  26
Date:  2014-04-25
Num Day:  27
not exists
Num Day:  28
not exists
---End week---
Num Day:  29
Date:  2014-04-28
Num Day:  30
Date:  2014-04-29
Num Day:  31
Date:  2014-04-30
Num Day:  32
Date:  2014-05-01
Num Day:  33
Date:  2014-05-02
Num Day:  34
not exists
Num Day:  35
not exists
---End week---
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, it feels to me like you're doing rather more parsing than you need to be. There's no point in parsing a constant - just call a constructor. And for `dateTemp`, why not store the parsed value instead of `result[12]`?  It's not really clear what's in `result[12]` though - it would really help if you'd give a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sorry for unclearly question. result[12] is the date retrieves from the query.
I was thinking a solution and this code working on dates difference: I'm calculating the difference from actual date of the query and previous calculated date. If the difference is more than 1 days, there is more than 1 day that is not calculate in the week...
I hope was clear...

Comment: It's not particularly clear, no. It would be *much* clearer with a short but complete example. I very much doubt that the problem is Android-specific, so I suggest you just write a simple Java console app which demonstrates what's wrong, including the sample data and expected/actual output.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've writed the sample code :)

Comment: That's not a short but complete program, is it? I want something I can copy, paste into a new text document, compile and run. (Also take the time to format it nicely...)

Comment: Yes, you can copy and paste. You must substitute the log.v with system.out.println and add the jodatime libraries...it might run...

Comment: I am not at home at the moment. If there are the problems with code, I fix when I go at home! :) Thanks so much!!!!!!

Comment: No, I can't just copy and paste into an empty file and compile. It doesn't declare a class, or a `main` method. While I could do all of that work (and fix the indentation), it's really up to you to make the question as simple as possible to answer.

Comment: Finally, if you're using Joda Time, why are you still using `SimpleDateFormat`? Prefer `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited the post! I followed your suggestions! :) 
For SimpleDateFormat question: Yes, I know...but I'm new in Jodatime libraries and I need to learn a better use...
Thanks!

Comment: A) What did you mean by "Cicle"? If a typo, you can edit to fix. B) Your example code is way too long and complicated as noted in the other comments.

Comment: @BasilBourque Sorry, I meant "cycle". I fixed the issue.
Anyway, I was looking for a better solution because my example code is too complicated, I know (and doesn't works)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next solution should be helpful:

```
final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); // like 'SimleDateFormat'
final List<String> month = Arrays.asList("2014-03-31", "2014-04-01", "2014-04-02", "2014-04-03", "2014-04-04",
          "2014-04-07", "2014-04-08", "2014-04-09", "2014-04-10", "2014-04-11",
          "2014-04-14", "2014-04-15", "2014-04-16", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-18",
          "2014-04-21", "2014-04-22", "2014-04-23", "2014-04-24", "2014-04-25",
          "2014-04-28", "2014-04-29", "2014-04-30", "2014-05-01", "2014-05-02");
final DateTime lastDate = dtf.parseDateTime(month.get(month.size() - 1)); // last date in 'month' array
final MutableDateTime dateIterator = new MutableDateTime(dtf.parseDateTime(month.get(0))); // first date in 'month' array
int count = 0;
for (;;dateIterator.addDays(1)) // start iteration day by day 
{
   count++;
   final String dateAsString = dtf.print(dateIterator); // convert iterator to String
   if (month.contains(dateAsString)) // 'month' array contains current date
   {
      System.out.println("Date: " + dateAsString);
   }
   else
   {  
      if (dateIterator.getDayOfWeek() == 1   // current date is first day of week but record is absent in db
          && dateIterator.isAfter(lastDate)) // and all records from db are processed
                                             // so let's break for-loop

      {
         break; // break for-loop
      }   
      System.out.println("not exists");
   }
   System.out.println("Num Day: " + String.valueOf(count));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! You're awesome! :) I've added the "end of week" management! I hope this is correct.